# Why my localhost dont send email transactional?

Tags: transactional-mail

My code is:

```
<?php
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));



// This is the template name from your etc/config.xml 
$template_id = 'exceptionCode';

// Who were sending to...
$email_to = 'teste@gmail.com';
$customer_name   = 'teste';

// Load our template by template_id
$email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

// Here is where we can define custom variables to go in our email template!
$email_template_variables = array(
    'customer_name' => $customerName
    // Other variables for our email template.
);

// I'm using the Store Name as sender name here.
$sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
// I'm using the general store contact here as the sender email.
$sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
$email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
$email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 

//Send the email!
$email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);

?>
```

Then i run in root dir and empty blank page shows nothing and i not recieve the mail. Why? I follow the steps https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/08/28/custom-transactional-emails-in-magento/ and doesnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The blank page based on what you are describing sounds to be simply that your not rendering any actual page therefore getting no output.

As to not sending out e-mail, it is likely a result of not having a mail server installed on localhost.

Try installing sendmail/postfix or some other mail service on the server. We use http://mailcatcher.me/ to be able to catch e-mails from being sent out in development environments but see the results instead in your web browser as it would be received by a mail client. This is a good way to prevent clients from getting notifications as a result of tests then being unable to find corresponding orders etc.

Comment: hi, i have this module instaled and configured for use. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html 
In her, the shows in "run test" is:
SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: hello@example.com from: owner@example.com.
Test email was sent successfully.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.
Required database tables exist.
Testing complete, support@aschroder.com for support.
everthing ok, but in PHP dont send nothing